# How to send an image both side using WIFI Direct?

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am working on an app where ,i am able to send an image only one way,from client to groupowner.How can i send it in both ways?

Answer (score 0):

I had done bi-directional data transfer in my project. In Wifi Direct group owner Ip is decided by OS itself which is known to both devices i.e Server as well as client. Client know the IP of server on which it has to send data, But server don't know the client IP.

For that you have to send client IP address to server and store that address in sharedPrefrences. So you should initiate transfer silently when connection made so that server store the client IP, for next transfer.

```
Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
String WiFiClientIp = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
```

you can made a check while transfer i.e if IP don't match server Ip then send data to client IP.

For testing purpose when you send file from client to server, in AsyncTask doinbackground method you can get the IP address of client which is also decide by OS itself. Put that IP statically then you will be able to send file on client also.
I will share my code on github soon. I hope this info will help you.
Working Bi-Directional Data Transfer APK File-> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=anuj.wifidirect&hl=en